# Extracting data from the <br> tag - Jsoup

Tags: java, html, dom, web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to extract text from the
 tags in the following HTML as bullet points. The way my code prints it is one continuous string with some unnecessary text. I saw that I could do a `replace("<br>","\n")` but that doesn't help in this case and I get the Google HTML data along with it.

```
<div class="report-content" style="line-height:160%!important"> Read the side effects of Abacavir as described in the medical literature. In case of any doubt consult your doctor or pharmacist. 
<!-- Ezoic - under-first-paragraph - under_first_paragraph -->
<div id="ezoic-pub-ad-placeholder-101">
          <div id="google-ads-1" class="fleft"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            google_ad_client = "ca-pub-4864473589052117";
            google_ad_slot = "6404003758";
            google_ad_height = 250;
            ad1 = document.getElementById('google-ads-1');
                if (ad1.getBoundingClientRect().width) {
    google_ad_width = ad1.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    } else {
    google_ad_width = ad1.offsetWidth; // for old IE
    }
    google_ad_width=rwdscreenWidth;

        /*Full Width Ad*/
    if (google_ad_width>1024) {
    google_ad_width = 880;
    google_ad_height = 300;
    } 
    else if ((google_ad_width<1025) && (google_ad_width>959)) {
    google_ad_width = 605;
    google_ad_height = 300;
    }
    else if ((google_ad_width<960) && (google_ad_width>799)) {
    google_ad_width = 730;
    google_ad_height = 300;
    }
    else if ((google_ad_width<800) && (google_ad_width>767)) {
    google_ad_width = 600;
    google_ad_height = 300;
    }
    else if ((google_ad_width<768) && (google_ad_width>599)) {
    google_ad_width = 540;
    google_ad_height = 300;
    }
    else if ((google_ad_width<600) && (google_ad_width>479)) {
    google_ad_width = 420;
    google_ad_height = 250;
    }   
    else if ((google_ad_width<480) && (google_ad_width>300)) {
    google_ad_width = 300;
    google_ad_height = 250;
    }       
    else {
    google_ad_width = 300;
    google_ad_height = 250;
    }


    document.write (
    '<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:'
    + google_ad_width + 'px;height:'
    + google_ad_height + 'px" data-ad-client="'
    + google_ad_client + '" data-ad-slot="'
    + google_ad_slot + '"></ins>'
    );
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script><ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:600px;height:300px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-4864473589052117" data-ad-slot="6404003758" data-adsbygoogle-status="done"><ins id="aswift_1_expand" style="display:inline-table;border:none;height:300px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;visibility:visible;width:600px;background-color:transparent;"><ins id="aswift_1_anchor" style="display:block;border:none;height:300px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;visibility:visible;width:600px;background-color:transparent;"><iframe width="600" height="300" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true" onload="var i=this.id,s=window.google_iframe_oncopy,H=s&amp;&amp;s.handlers,h=H&amp;&amp;H[i],w=this.contentWindow,d;try{d=w.document}catch(e){}if(h&amp;&amp;d&amp;&amp;(!d.body||!d.body.firstChild)){if(h.call){setTimeout(h,0)}else if(h.match){try{h=s.upd(h,i)}catch(e){}w.location.replace(h)}}" id="aswift_1" name="aswift_1" style="left:0;position:absolute;top:0;width:600px;height:300px;"></iframe></ins></ins></ins>

    <script async="" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>

</div><!-- End Ezoic - under-first-paragraph - under_first_paragraph -->
<br><br> Sleep disturbances, headache, depressive disorders
<br><br> Digestive tract disorders like nausea, diarrhea
<br><br> Allergic reaction, which may be mild to severe
<br><br> Liver disease, which may cause nausea, jaundice, dark-colored urine, clay-colored stools
<br><br> Reaction to infections in the body due to improvement in the immune status
<br><br> Redistribution of fat resulting in thin limbs, fat abdomen and hump in upper back


<br>



                    <div class="pad10"></div><b>Other Precautions :&nbsp;</b>•  Monitor and treat the signs of lactic acidosis such as upset stomach, fluctuations in heartbeat,unexplained muscle pain, and difficulty in breathing.<br>

•  Patient's body fat and cardiac parameters should be measured regularly to avoid heart related illness.<br>
</div>
```

**My code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


            Connection.Response response = null;
            Document doc = null;

            final String url = "https://www.medindia.net/drugs/medication-side-effects/abacavir.htm";


                response = Jsoup.connect(url)
                        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
                        .execute();

                doc = response.parse();



                String text =doc.select("div.report-content").first().text();
                Jsoup.clean(text, Whitelist.basic());

                System.out.println(text);

        }

    }
```

**My Output**

> Read the side effects of Abacavir as described in the medical
>   literature. In case of any doubt consult your doctor or pharmacist.
>   Sleep disturbances, headache, depressive disorders Digestive tract
>   disorders like nausea, diarrhea Allergic reaction, which may be mild
>   to severe Liver disease, which may cause nausea, jaundice,
>   dark-colored urine, clay-colored stools Reaction to infections in the
>   body due to improvement in the immune status Redistribution of fat
>   resulting in thin limbs, fat abdomen and hump in upper back Other
>   Precautions : ? Monitor and treat the signs of lactic acidosis such as
>   upset stomach, fluctuations in heartbeat,unexplained muscle pain, and
>   difficulty in breathing. ? Patient's body fat and cardiac parameters
>   should be measured regularly to avoid heart related illness.

**Expected Output**

```
 Sleep disturbances, headache, depressive disorders
 Digestive tract disorders like nausea, diarrhea
 Allergic reaction, which may be mild to severe
 Liver disease, which may cause nausea, jaundice, dark-colored urine, clay-
 colored stools
 Reaction to infections in the body due to improvement in the immune status
```

Comment: br is breakline, there is no data in that tag

Answer (score 1):

`<br>` is known as an [empty element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Empty_element), which means it **can not** contain data. Because it's an empty element, `<br>` and `<br/>` behave the same way: they close immediately. They do not (and can not) contain data. The text is contained by the enclosing `<div>` with the `.report-content` class.